# Pymqi throws exception ImportError at library import

Tags: python, windows, ibm-mq, pymqi

I'm getting strange ImportError exception while importing to my script pymqi.

1. I installed WebSphere MQ for windows 7.5, both user and client versions.
2. I tried to run pip install pymqi, but there was problems at C++ compiling.
3. I moved headers from `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\include` to `C:\Python27\include` and tried to run, there were linking problem.
4. I moved some `.lib` files from `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\Lib` to `C:\Python27\libs` and it compiled well.

Then I tried this code:

```
import pymqi
queue_manager = "QM"
channel = "SVRCONN"
host = "192.168.1.252"
port = "1434"
conn_info = "%s(%s)" % (host, port)
qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info)
qmgr.disconnect()
```

And at import library I got:

```
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pymqe.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pymqe.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: �� ������ ��������� ������.
```

Where after some manipulations I got that `...��...` means: it can't find module.

5. I decide that done something wrong. Downloaded [pymqi-1.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymqi) and done `setup.py build` + `setup.py install`, that finished successfully. But problem still was there.
6. I moved all DLL files from `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin` to `C:\Python27`

And got another ImportError exception with text, that may be translated as "Bad try to access to memory address".

7. I tried springpython library, but it uses pymqi inside, so falls with same exceptions.

How can I finally solve this problem? I guess there may be problem at WebSphere side, but how to check it? "WS Explorer" runs well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Re-installing the client seemed to fix it. Ensure that you have the following items in your PATH variable:

C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\samples\bin